# How to set dynamically values to Yaxis using MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, graph, mpandroidchart

Is there anyway to set dynamically values to Yaxis using MPAndroidChart. I searched SO question but here I didn't get any answer. I have to set run-time values to Yaxis. I have also tried setGranularity() but this method is showing me error like `can't resolve method setGranularity(float)`.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
 private ArrayList<Entry> setYAxisValues(){
    ArrayList<Entry> yVals = new ArrayList<Entry>();

    //Change to your values 

    yVals.add(new Entry(0, 6));
    yVals.add(new Entry(1, 4));
    yVals.add(new Entry(2, 5));
    yVals.add(new Entry(3, 4));
    yVals.add(new Entry(4, 3));
    yVals.add(new Entry(5, 2));
    yVals.add(new Entry(6, 3));
    yVals.add(new Entry(7, 4));
    yVals.add(new Entry(8, 5));
    yVals.add(new Entry(9, 3));
    yVals.add(new Entry(10, 2));
    yVals.add(new Entry(11,4));




    return yVals;
}

private void setData() {

    //call this method to set data
    ArrayList<Entry> yVals = setYAxisValues();

    LineDataSet set1;

    // create a dataset and give it a type
    set1 = new LineDataSet(yVals, "DataSet 1");

    set1.setFillAlpha(110);
    set1.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    set1.setCircleColor(Color.WHITE);
    set1.setLineWidth(1f);
    set1.setCircleRadius(3f);
    set1.setDrawCircleHole(false);
    set1.setValueTextSize(9f);

    ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<ILineDataSet>();
    dataSets.add(set1); // add the datasets

    // create a data object with the datasets
    LineData data = new LineData(dataSets);

    // set data to LineChart
    mChart.setData(data);
    mChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(4); // allow 20 values to be displayed at once on the x-axis, not more
    mChart.moveViewToX(10);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to set dynamically values to Xaxis and Yaxis both axis? If yes then how? I have already set the dynamic values to Xaxis and I want to set dynamically values to Yaxis too.

Comment: what do you mean by, "set dyamically"

Comment: Means set the values on runtime.

Comment: do you want the values to be downloaded from the server or to add them manually